# How to stop retry on bounce in Amazon SES Golang SDK

Tags: go, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES SDK for golang. I want to stop retrying on bounces (hard & soft). Following is my code:

```
import(
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ses"
)

CharSet := "UTF-8"
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(AwsRegion)},
)

/* Create an SES client in the session */
svc := ses.New(sess)

/* Assemble the email */
input := &ses.SendEmailInput{
    Destination: &ses.Destination{
        CcAddresses: []*string{},
        ToAddresses: []*string{
            aws.String(test1@example.com),
        },
    },
    Message: &ses.Message{
        Body: &ses.Body{
            Html: &ses.Content{
                Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
                Data:    aws.String(EMAILBODYHTML),
            },
        },
        Subject: &ses.Content{
            Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
            Data:    aws.String(SUBJECT),
        },
    },
    ReplyToAddresses: []*string{aws.String(test3@example.com)},
    Source:           aws.String(test2@example.com),
}

/* Attempt to send the email */
_, err = svc.SendEmail(input)
if err != nil {
    // handle errors
}
```

Can I stop retrying of bounce emails using SDK by applying any option ? If yes, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SNS to notice there is bounce mail. Then subscribe http service to your SNS topic. Bounce email need to handle with your script and save bounce email address to your database. Next time you send email check on your database, if it existed then no need you send email since the address mark as bounce.